# Mysql: optimizing a query that uses one column or the other

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization, composite

The table contains chat data with `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` columns both individually indexed properly. My query is to get all chat msgs that a particular user participated in i.e.
`SELECT * FROM chat WHERE from_user_id = 123  OR to_user_id = 123;`

When run these two conditions separately they are using their respective indices but when they're stitched together with an OR the explain query is using a much higher estimated number of rows. How would you optimize it?

[See screenshot of all these queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZgTK.png)

Comment: We need more information to help you. [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) and then [edit] your question. And, please be aware that `SELECT *` is a notorious performance antipattern on large tables.

Answer (score 1):

Turn `OR` into `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM chat WHERE from_user_id = 123  OR to_user_id = 123;
```

-->

```
( SELECT * FROM chat WHERE from_user_id = 123 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT * FROM chat WHERE to_user_id = 123 )
ORDER BY date;
```

And have

```
INDEX(from_user_id),
INDEX(to_user_id)
```

so that *each* `SELECT` is well optimized.

If you will be paginating, see this on how to make `OFFSET` work:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or

If you have other flavors of `SELECT`, let's see them.  Different techniques are needed for different queries.  For example, if you sometimes need `AND`:

```
SELECT ... WHERE from_user_id = 123
             AND to_user_id = 7777
```

Needs *either* of these:

```
INDEX(from_user_id, to_user_id)
INDEX(to_user_id, from_user_id)
```

If you need both the OR and the AND queries, then I would recommend *both* of these compound indexes and *not* the single-column indexes I recommended above.

(The link above is in the middle of a blog discussion indexing; read it all.)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Thanks.  Hehe -- no T-shirt.  I have over 50 t-shirts from companies and conferences.

Comment: You should be getting something...eventually.  See here: [Swag is coming back!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back)

Comment: Socks!?  That's an interesting swag.

Answer (score 0):

Multi column indexes in MySQL let you use all the fields in the index from left to right. For example if you have an INDEX (col1, col2, col3, col4) then the index will be applied for searches with a WHERE clause like `col1 = 'A'` or `col1 = 'A' AND col2 = 'B'` or `col1 = 'A' AND col2 ='B' AND col3 = 'C' AND col4 = 'D'`, but this particular index won't be used for anything like `WHERE col2 = 'B'` or `WHERE col3 = 'C' AND col4 = 'D'` because the search fields are not left most in the index definition. You would have to add additional indexes to cover those fields.

So, if you create a multi-column index :

```
 CREATE INDEX idx ON chat (from_user_id, to_user_id);
```

whenever you perform a select like below ,

```
select * from chat where from_user_id = 123;
select * from chat where from_user_id = 123 or to_user_id=123;
```

the index will be applied by mysql in both the above cases.

For the below query index will not be applied,

```
select * from chat where to_user_id=123;
select * from chat where to_user_id=123 or from_user_id = 123;
```

So, plan your indexes according to your need.